# XmlSerializer is there any way it could fail to write but not throw an exception?

Tags: c#, file, serialization

I have this bit of code:

```
var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SessionModel));

OutputSavedLocally = false;

try
{
   if (!Directory.Exists(_outputFileLocation))
   {
       Directory.CreateDirectory(_outputFileLocation);
   }

   Logger.Instance.LogDebug("Saving data to " + _outputFileLocation);

   using (var writer = new StreamWriter(_outputFileLocation + string.Format(Consts.OutputFileName, _subject.SubjectNumber)))
   {
       serialiser.Serialize(writer, _session);
   }
}
catch (Exception)
{
   Logger.Instance.LogInfo("Couldn't write file {0} to network location. Saving locally.");

   // Other exception handling logic.
}
```

It's attempting to write to a location on a shared network drive, where it will be picked up by another application on another device. Most of the time it works fine.

However, it seems to have happened to a tester that the file will not have been written (i.e. not created at all). This guy is in another country so I can't just go and look at the device.

That `Logger` class just writes info to a log file, both using `LogDebug()` and `LogInfo()`. Judging by the log file, the file is being written without an exception - i.e. the "Couldn't write to file..." log entry never appears (The "Saving data to..." does), but the file doesn't appear in the destination.

My question is, is there any way the file could fail to write but not throw an exception?

Comment: @Sinatr - I don't think I mentioned that I was over-writing a file at any point. The file would have a different name each time, also it's archived to another location as it's consumed. In any case, if it was simply a problem of over-writing an existing file, the original file would be found, not overwritten, in the destination, which it is  not.

Comment: @Sinatr - not there